# Using an absolute value in a .net installer

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, installation, wix

I'm using WIX files to build an MSI package.

It works using an environment value

```
<Property Id="ProgramFilesDir" Value="$(env.ProgramFiles)" />
```

but doesn't seem to understand absolute values, e.g

```
<Property Id="ProgramFilesDir" Value="X:\MyFolder\" />
```

Is there anywhere else I need to declare absolute values?

Comment: The question is not very clear. In what context are you using these values?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that my code sample wasn't included.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to understand"?

Comment: Also, note that "$(env.ProgramFiles)" is also an absolute path, just one that is filled in by the WIX preprocessor. It does NOT mean "take the value of this environment variable on the target machine", it takes the value of the environment variable on YOUR machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using your computer's paths, as no one guarantees, for example, that the target machine is going to have drive X at all. Instead use the built-in paths, like so:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
```

Comment: The problem is that I know there will be an x drive becuase only one person will be installing the software.

Comment: I would still advise against (you can never know where the MSI will end up). If you insist, you can try to give the properties some value that works, and then change it in Orca and see what happens.